# Autoresizing issue in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, storyboard, swift3, autoresize, xcode8

=== **EDIT** ========

This issue is now solved in **Xcode 8.1**. I have checked.

================

I don't know auto-layout properly. So, I am using autoresizing option in my all apps and it's fine for me. I am able to fulfill my all requirements by this without any issue.

Now in Xcode 8, I have migrated my old swift project to swift 3. Now issue arises.

[image: Storyboard SS]

See in image, I have set Autoresizing, and its working fine without issue in all devices until now and this project is live in AppStore, so that I can't show the UI or storyboard.

Now I have to do some update in project. So I am working in Xcode 8 now. But my autoresizing not working properly, as all the controls are come in center and UI is messed up.

[image: Output image]

And the issue persists in device also. I have checked in simulator and device as well. But problem is there also. Any suggestion and help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Yesterday there is issue in runtime only, But Today storyboard also changed views like this image

[image: Storyboard image]

Which means the whole UI design is messed up. This is weird.

Comment: same here ... and its a bug in xcode ... and there is issue with auto layout too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394316/xcode-8-gm-seed-storyboard-layout-issue

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 ok but there is an answer to update frames. But what to do in this case?

Comment: nothing in this case ... because I did try everything but nothing works for me

Comment: This happen for all view inside Scrollview only?

Comment: @CRDave No. Not only scrollview, All other view controllers without scrollview also have same issue. Only tableview cell are stable with no change.

Comment: I have same problem, it is happening on all views. Any solution so far?

Comment: I think it is xcode bug with autoresizing and I have already report a bug to apple bug report support and waiting for their reply.

Comment: xcode 8.1 beta still has this issue.

Comment: @Max, did you find solution?

Comment: @gstream79 No, still not get a proper solution.

Comment: Same problem here. XCode 8 seems the worst XCode ever. :(

Comment: This issue is now gone for me with Xcode 8.1 GM seed.

Comment: @Dennis I will check with Xcode 8.1 GM seed.

Answer (score 7):

Facing same issue. As a my point of view this problem is occurred when we use autoresizing and set only inner autoresizingMask to any view controller. Like,

[image]

If we use also boundary autoresizingMask at that time not facing this issue. Like,

[image]

I don't know this is actual bug of xcode 8 or remove this functionality in xcode 8.

So, Finally my suggestion is that we need to use auto layout in xcode 8.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please make an appropriate answer, or wait for a solution from the public.

Comment: this is not an answer either. Answer is meant to be a solution and you last sentence, if it could be the solution, is supposed to be posted rather as a comment.

Comment: yep, the bug is serious and still there, we must be able to disable AutLayout too and have no issues on Storyboard, as we always could do up to Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: This is how Apple force you to use autolayout. Make autoresize break your app.

Comment: @Rocotilos I don't know this is bug or apple remove autoresize functionality .

Comment: Hope it's a bug. But probably Apple don't care about an old feature.

Comment: **We need to use auto layout in xcode 8** That's it, no other way until Apple fix (if they want to fix it someday...)

Comment: See my fix below. It works in Xcode 8 and can be used as a stopgap measure until you're ready to bite the bullet and recode your storyboard using auto layout.

Answer (score 7):

Please try to uncheck autoresizing from xib or storyboard. And in`viewDidLoad` set `[_scrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];`

**Edit:** In case of storyboard uncheck `Resize view from NIB` option.

Comment: in my case it brings 80% UI to its original place but when I try to correct 20% myself using storyboard, things get horrible... How can Apple ship Xcode 8 without testing old project compatibility with it

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about storyboards but I've found a temporary solution for xib files. In Utilities panel (right hand panel) select File Inspector tab. Under Interface Builder Document section, select the file to open in "XCode 7.x". It will ask you to confirm that you do not want to use XCode 8 features, save the file and close it.

[image]

Comment: It will lock the storyboard that time only.. Again when you access storyboard it will use 8.0.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need to do the same thing every time I edit the file.

Comment: Thats why this is not a solution, It can work until we got perfect and steady solution.

Comment: As i said this is a temporary way to make it work till Apple updates XCode and solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue for scrollView in Xcode8

I have an one solution to work with scrollView

First take a simple UIView and add all component which you want add to in scrollView and give that component to autoSizing

And also take one scrollView and programmatically set view frame and also set scrollView contentSize and add your view into scrollView

like wise, in my case I added this code in viewDidLoad for swift project

```
// add view to scrollview

self.scrollObjForNextAppointment.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollObjForNextAppointment.frame.size.width,height:410)

self.viewForScrollContent.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.scrollObjForNextAppointment.frame.size.width,height:410)

self.scrollObjForNextAppointment.addSubview(self.viewForScrollContent)
```

Comment: What about storyboard which mess up the views UI? Each time we need to set it?

Comment: not need to set everytime, it's only happen in scrollView, not in view

Comment: Then if we use scrollview by code only then no need to use in storyboard, Thats not proper solution for interface builder.

Comment: you can take scrollView in storyboard, not need to add scrollView by coding, just take empty scrollView not add any UIComponent in that scrollView, take another view in storyBoard and in that add your all component and give them to autoSizing and add that view in scrollview by coding.

Comment: There is no difference if we take blank scrollview in storyboard or add it through code, in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 8 beta 2 solved this problem!

Answer (score 1):

**Update** the issue seems to have been fixed in Xcode 8.1

---

Having the same issue and I've found that the offender here is the **UIScrollView** element. Just move everything outside of your scroller and you will see that everything works just fine, like before.

Which means one possible workaround would be to place your scrollable content in an ordinary UIView, then replacing it with UIScrollView at run time, programmatically.

Comment: There are many views without scrollview and also have same issue. And Scrollview only is not problem.

Comment: @Max have you tried to move everything outside the scroller and see if it works? It worked for me.

Comment: @mojuba is the UIScrollView not on self.view so what is the possibility if i take another view on the main view it will give the right result

Comment: @AhmedSahib the issue is fixed now if you update Xcode to any version >= 8.1 so no need to worry

Answer (score 1):

Solved by unchecking "Auto Resize Subviews" to ScrollView

[image]

Comment: but i need to resize it according to screen size.

Comment: It solves the problem but we have to deal with Different Screen sizes

Comment: In my case there is no problem for different screen sizes, don't remove the auto resize properties for scrollview.

Comment: in my case I am not using autolayouts

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at:

[Autoresizing under iOS 10 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514044/autoresizing-under-ios-10-doesnt-work/39902192#39902192)

In response to max, yes, resizing a bunch of subviews can be a pain. That's why I suggested adding a single "content view" to the scroll view and moving all of your existing subviews inside of that view. Autosize the subviews inside of the content view just as you did with the scrollview, and autosize the content view to the scrollview.

It's that content view that you're then resizing inside viewDidLayoutSubviews.

And again, the "content view" inside of the scrollview construct is pretty much the standard way to get auto-sizing scroll views using autolayout, so it should be considered a best practice.

That method is described here...

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

My method seems a little convoluted, but I was able to patch up a storyboard with about a dozen scenes and Vc's in about 15 minutes. It would have taken much, much, much longer to rebuild everything using auto layout.

Comment: If the questions are duplicates please flag one as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Apple just came out with XCode 8.2, which fixes this problem for me. I have been using XCode 7.3.1 for my interface design parallel to 8.1, but I can now use 8.2 without any problems.

The storyboard gets updated with widths and height of frames though, to accommodate the new 'View as:' functionality. Though it doesn't seem to affect running on device/simulator.

Curiously, the bugfix it is not noted in the [XCode 8.2 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW9).

*Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138079/1437096)*