# MKMapView defaults to 1000x1000 in Xcode8

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I'm wondering if anyone else has the issue that MKMapView (Or maybe it relates to many other Views?) does a strange thing where it defaults to 1000x1000 in size the first time I load a screen. When I segue to another screen, and segue back to the map screen, then it actually followed up all my constraints.

This didn't happen with Xcode7 and I wonder if someone knows there's a known bug in Xcode8 or something?

MapKitView get loaded programmatically and is added as a subview within my View that has the constraints.

```
MKMapView *mapkitView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.aConstrainedView.frame];
[self.mapkitView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapkitView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapkitView setRotateEnabled:NO];
[self.aConstrainedView addSubview:self.mapkitView];
```

Could this be related to [Autoresizing issue in Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526156/autoresizing-issue-in-xcode-8) ?

Comment: what's the prob exactly ?

Comment: The problem is that the map is not following the size of the parent View. 

Investigating with the "Debug View Hierarchy" showed that the MKMapView had a size of 1000x1000 and was out of bounds to the parent view..

Comment: set the frame size of mapView in inside program see my ans below ..

Comment: I'm seeing something similar with a storyboard-created MKMapView. Possibly related to [this bug](http://www.openradar.me/28325425) in Xcode 8?

Comment: Exactly encountered the same issue in xcode 8. Map changes when i reopens xcode and the my application and go to my view controller in storyboard where the mapview is present. All the constraints fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialiser should use the `bounds` of its superview, not the `frame`:

```
MKMapView *mapkitView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.aConstrainedView.bounds];
```

Set a breakpoint on this line and in the debugger use:

```
(lldb) po self.aConstrainedView.bounds
```

to ensure the width and height are correct. If you're adding the map view in viewDidLoad, then that's too early. You should override:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    dispatch_once(
        // Add map view here
    );
}
```

and add your code in there, as that gets called after your subviews have all been laid out according to your constraints.

Comment: For me, adding the map view in viewDidLoad was the case. I moved it to the suggested solution and dispatched it once.

Comment: It can only be fixed via code.? What about storyboard and constraints.