# Application design is not display properly in simulator after updating xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have updated xcode 8 and then tested application in **iphone 6 (ios 10) simulator**.
Application desiging is not showing properly as it should be.
In xcode 8, storyboard designing is not proper.
Storyboard showing designs properly but runtime it's now showing properly.
I'm not able to get any solution.
If anyone know the answer please suggest me.

Comment: Have you checked your constrains?

Comment: Pics, or it's not happening.

Comment: Which type of constrains ? I'm not using Auto Layout in application.@Ondre_

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526156/autoresizing-issue-in-xcode-8/39544145#39544145

Comment: So Is there issue in auto resizing concept in xcode 8 ? Because till now all things are working properly . I reviewed your answer but i'm not able to get proper solution. @KeyurHirani

Comment: You can use auto layout.

Comment: this problem occurred after update xcode 8.0.....for temporary solution you can save this file as Xcode 7.x

Comment: Any solution without using auto layout ? @KeyurHirani

Comment: I have no any solution without auto layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39918813/6619234 this answer for scrollview but its working for all the design issue......i know this is temporary but we can wait till apple developer solve it.

Answer (score 2):

from storyboard, Select your view controller and set proper device from View As button. If your storyboard is designed using previous version of Xcode, try selecting iPhone SE from "View As" as shown in below image.

[image]

[image: selecting View As option]